# Should I duplicate a solution that is an answer for two different questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I wrote code by following an answer from *[SqlException from Entity Framework - New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113498/sqlexception-from-entity-framework-new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-ther/37762186#37762186)*. However after 50,000 records I've got an OutofMemoryException and was able to solve it with the answer from another question, *[Entity framework large data set, out of memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169859/entity-framework-large-data-set-out-of-memory-exception/18169894#18169894)*.

My final solution solved both errors, and I was able to provide more details than existing answers, so I decided to add answers with my solution to both questions. I believed it would be useful for readers of both questions. I’ve added the full answer with code snippet to one of the questions and relatively short answer to the second question with reference to the snippet in the first question.

> Thanks to [Luke McGregor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18169894/52277) I've implemented renewal of context
>   for each batch. It described in my answer to [SqlException from Entity Framework - New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113498/sqlexception-from-entity-framework-new-transaction-is-not-allowed-because-ther/37762186#37762186).
>   It includes code snippet.

I decided not to duplicate the snippet ([DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) as it belongs to Stack Overflow, not to external site. However my short answer was deleted by reviewers as low quality (with different reasons: "This should be a comment, not an answer.", "This does not provide an answer to the question.", and even "Please don't add "thank you" as an answer.")

Was I wrong that didn’t duplicate the snippet (and make the answer complete), or just unlucky, that reviewers didn’t realised that the link refers to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Questions and answers get deleted all the time on SO, making the link dead (to everyone below 10k rep)

Comment: IMO it should have been *two* answers, each emphasizing how it solves the question it's posted under. I mean, great for you that you managed to solve two problems in one go, but that doesn't mean the solution for problem A belongs under a question for problem B, DRY or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solve the problem asked in the question. Mention, reference and, if it's sufficiently critical, incorporate solutions to major supplemental problems but make it clear what in your code solves what.**

---

SO answers are supposed to teach best practices.

In your case, when solving the "new transaction is not allowed" issue, there's a supplemental "out of memory" issue that arises if the data set is sufficiently large. So anyone solving the first problem has to have the second one in mind, and any good solution to the first one should address both (50000 records isn't so large by DB standards, really, so one cannot claim that it's only warranted for enterprise-level data mining and such).

But the reverse isn't true: the "new transaction is not allowed" is not a part of the "out of memory" issue. So a solution to the former is off topic in a question about the latter.

So,

- In the "new transaction is not allowed" question, solve both problems but make it clear that you are also solving the second and why you need to. Reference that question and make it clear (this way or another) which elements of your code solve which.
- In the "out of memory" question, solve only the out of memory problem. You might retain some other code but it can only serve as framing for illustration -- and as such, will likely have to be drastically reduced and/or replaced with pseudocode so that it doesn't distract from that question's topic.

  - In your particular case, AFAICS, you didn't find anything that wasn't already covered by existing answers to that question, so there's no use adding your own.

Answer (score 8):

No, you shouldn't *duplicate* your answer, you should keep your answer specific to the question. You don't want to conflate or confuse with your answer.

From your description it sounds like you only "solved" or significantly improved upon one issue - specifically the issue that resulted in the OutOfMemoryException. It seems that the SqlException was largely mitigated by following the approach from an existing answer?

If this is the case then you should submit a new answer on the [large dataset question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18169859/109702).

If you haven't significantly improved on that [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18169894/109702) but you have come up with a reasonable improvement then you can edit that into the existing answer - the Stack Exchange network is fully supportive of communal editing and improving of answers.

Alternatively if your solution is sufficiently different then you can post your own question and self answer it.